# Compare two word documents to show only similarities

Tags: microsoft-word, comparison

I am working with two huge Word documents and I want to see only the similarities between. I have been using the compare function under the review tab however it is showing a lot of deletions and insertions. I want to see only what was "moved," basically I want to know if stuff was the same between the two documents but I don't want to know anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Draftable for Word](https://draftable.com/word#).  It is much, much better than the compare that's built into Word.  There is a free trial.

The compare plugin for notepad++ is good, so I suppose you could copy just the unformatted text into text files and compare that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two Word files to check similarities between them I found this tool useful: 
https://www.prepostseo.com/plagiarism-comparison-search

It's free also you can compare your file with a simple plain text.

Comment: You should probably note that without a membership, the scope is very limited.